# A philosophical question on probability theory

Tags: probability, logic, philosophy

This question is philosophical in nature. The example is taken from theology, but one may invent more examples, including these more scientific than mine. Nevertheless it is a valid mathematical issue.

Accordingly (my understanding of) Protestant theology:

1. Salvation of a human does not directly depend on his deeds, because salvation is by faith only.
2. But salvation "indirectly" depends on deeds: salvation depends on faith and deeds also depend on faith.

Or replacing the concrete question with more abstract one:

1. A does not directly depend on B.
2. But A indirectly depends on B: A depends on C and B also depend on C.

I ask you to formalize in terms of probability theory (or some other kind of logic) these my informal musings.

Comment: What is the exact question. Is there a probability you want to calculate?

Comment: @Marc: No I do not intend to calculate a probability. I want to formalize "X depends on Y" and show that the item 1 and item 2 in my question do not contradict to each other.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking.  I think you are using "directly" as a synonym for "explicitly".  It often happens that there are dependences which are not explicit...famously, murder rates go up as ice cream consumption increases (presumably because very hot weather makes some people want ice cream, but it also makes some people extremely irritable). Thus you have a clear dependence though it is hardly explicit.   Can you clarify your question a bit?  Perhaps, clarify what you mean by "directly".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a draw of a card from a deck, let A be to draw a spade and B to draw a king. Then A does not depend on B, in fact A,B are independent. However if C were say to draw the queen of spades, then each of A and B would definitely depend on C.